# Trouble with this if-statement

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am coding in Java and using TextPad editor.

I am trying to write code that sets "r" equal to a certain value depending on whether the user is male or female. I have already asked the user to put "1" if they are male and "2" if they are female.

I have set r as a double. 
D, and weight have been defined by the user earlier in the code.

Here is the code that I am trying to use and it keeps giving me an error saying that I have not defined "r".

```
if (gender == 1)
   r = 0.73D;
if (gender == 2)
   r = 0.66D;
else 
   System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2 for male or female.");

alcoholAbsored = (3.701*D)/(weight*r);
```

All of the code compiles until I get to the formula for alcoholAbsorbed and then tells me r is not defined. Technically there is no problem with the if/else statement when I compile but then when I try to use r there becomes a problem. I've ended up using this code for now but this is not really what I want because what if the user puts something other than 1 or 2?

```
if (gender == 1)
   r = 0.73D;
else
   r = 0.66D;

alcohol absorbed = (3.701*D)/(weight*r);
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I might go about fixing it? Please and thank you!

Comment: java !== javascript

Comment: declare r above the ifs statements... var r;

Comment: Declare r globally. And initialise it with some value

Comment: Actually in your previous code the else part does not initialises the r. Thats why you are getting that error

Comment: But the value of r changes depending on whether the user enters 1 or 2 for male or female. r is not a static value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that in the first version, if it goes to the else block (which it will even if the user has entered 1) then `r` won't be initialized so at the next line it cannot find any value for it. The correct code would be something like this:

```
if (gender == 1)
    r = 0.73D;
else if (gender == 2)
    r = 0.66D;
else {
    r = -1D;
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2 for male or female.");
}
if ( r != -1D)
    alcoholAbsored = (3.701*D)/(weight*r);
```

Or:

```
if (gender == 1 || gender == 2){
    if (gender == 1)
        r = 0.73D;
    else
        r = 0.66D;
    alcoholAbsored = (3.701*D)/(weight*r);
}
else 
    System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2 for male or female.");
```

Comment: Do I need to put the alcoholAbsorbed formula in an if-statement?

Comment: No, but you just need to make sure that `r` has been initialized in all the possible branches that reach to `alcoholAbsorbed`.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to code like this

```
if(gender==1 || gender==2)
 {
   if (gender == 1)
     r = 0.73D;
   else if (gender == 2)
     r = 0.66D;

   alcoholAbsored = (3.701*D)/(weight*r);
   // do something
 }
else 
 {
   System.out.println("Please enter 1 or 2 for male or female.");
 }
```

Comment: Hey TNT. I am posting it from my mobile. If the code is understandable. I think there is no need to shifting curly braces and scope statements.